# Is there a quick way to indent tags in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Org-mode seems to put tags assigned by `C-c C-q` a fixed number of tab stops after the headline. However, with editing, tag addition, and increased headline length, the tag display can get really ragged and hard to read.

Is there a way to tidy tags? There are a number of [ways](http://orgmode.org/manual/Clean-view.html) to tidy up [the tree in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771981/how-to-keep-indentation-with-emacs-org-mode-visual-line-mode) but nothing turns up for fixing the tags.

A simple tag tidier would for example right-justify all the tags to the right side of the window or 2+ tab stops past the longest headline.

Comment: Have a look at the variable `org-tags-column`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Setting-tags.html

Comment: It may be blasphemy for me to say this, but I prefer using Google -- it gives hits for not only the Emacs manual, but questions and answers relating to the same or similar issues.  I find the questions / answers / comments more helpful than merely reading the manual.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As reported by lawlist in the comments, the "set tags" command `C-c C-q`, when prefaced by `C-u`, will snap all tags in the buffer to the `org-tags-column`. This is a start and good enough for now--changing the variable will probably do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last part of your question, there are some hacks for always right-justifying tags. The hack detailed here (`ba/org-adjust-tags-column`):
http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#orgheadline64
hooks into 
`window-configuration-change-hook`, `before-save-hook` and `after-save-hook` to right-justify tags in display and fix it whenever window size is changed. In saving to files tags are written with just a space between headline and tag (avoids whitespace-versioning trouble). It has worked well for me, but I don't use it now since I mostly use `variable-pitch-mode` for org.